# Can't start activity in Android studio using SqliteDatabaseHelper

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to create a simple application and I'm storing my data in a SQLiteDatabase , but the problem is when I type my credentials the application shut down immediatly without showing anything on logcat.
Is it possible to call our database and work on it out of `onCreate` method in our main activiy?
Here's my **MainActivity** code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.username)
    EditText username;
    @BindView(R.id.password)
    EditText password;
    @BindView(R.id.buttonConnect)
    Button buttonConnect;

    //Calling our database
    final DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.buttonConnect)
    public void onConnect() {
        if (!emptyFields()) {
            User user = dbHelper.queryUser(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
            if (user != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, RestaurantCategories.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Welcome " + user.getUsername(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                password.setText("");
            }
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Empty Fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private boolean emptyFields() {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(username.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(password.getText().toString())) {
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and this My **Database queries** codes :

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DatabaseOptions.DB_NAME, null,DatabaseOptions.DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //Create table
        db.execSQL(DatabaseOptions.CREATE_USERS_TABLE_);

        // Inserting our login credentials
        initialInsertion(db,"aladin","alloallo123");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DatabaseOptions.USERS_TABLE);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void initialInsertion(SQLiteDatabase db,String username,String password) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DatabaseOptions.USERNAME,username);
        values.put(DatabaseOptions.PASSWORD,password);
        db.insert(DatabaseOptions.USERS_TABLE,null,values);
        db.close();
    }

    // To verify credentials in our login page !
    public User queryUser(String username, String password) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        User user = null;

        Cursor cursor = db.query(DatabaseOptions.USERS_TABLE, new String[]{DatabaseOptions.ID,
                        DatabaseOptions.USERNAME, DatabaseOptions.PASSWORD}, DatabaseOptions.USERNAME
                        + "=? and " + DatabaseOptions.PASSWORD + "=?",
                new String[]{username, password}, null, null, null, "1");
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            user = new User(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
        }
        // return user
        return user;
    }


}
```

The Idea is since I don't have a register page I want to insert directly to my database in the methode `OnCreate` that's why I'm calling the function `initialInsertion`

Ps: **DatabaseOptions** is a  different class where I create database & tables ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a crash in JVM code, there's also a stacktrace to go with it. You might have a logcat filter or something that hides it though.

In your `initialInsertion()` you're closing the database you didn't open yourself. That's an error. Remove the `close()` call there.

(That database `onCreate()` code path gets triggered by the `getReadableDatabase()` in your `queryUser()` - that's what you'd be seeing in the stacktrace.)

Comment: Thank you I just needed to remove the close() function , and it worked